How to downgrade bootloader Pi4 2GB from 2023 to 2020
So I’ve seen this question before but there was no answer unfortunately. I want to download the bootloader for a specific RetroPie image. I’ve flashed my 4GB and 8GB pi4 (getting that green screen) but on a 2GB pi4 it doesn’t work. Any ideas how to do so?

"it doesn't work" ... in what way? do you get a red screen?

Nothing at all, it just flashes green for a second and blank screen. Whereas the 4gb and 8gb cards I get a solid green light. Very strange
